# External API calls from the frontend or backend?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api

**Scenario:**
I have a Node and Angular web app.
It needs to call an external api (a third party service) for data (more specifically this: https://api.represent.me/api/questions/).

**Question:**
Is it better to make this external call from the Angular frontend: `GET http://thirdpartyservice.com/api/data` or have the frontend calling a same domain Node endpoint: `GET http://example.com/node-backend-api` which then calls `GET http://thirdpartyservice.com/api/data` which then fetches and processes the data from the third party api before passing it back to angular?

**Thoughts:**

- I guess two api calls is less desirable, but it is on the same domain
  so would this not really be an issue?
- GETing from the Node side would be more secure (especially if secret
  keys were used), and also mask the fact that a third party service is
  used.
- CORS stuff might get in the way if calling from the frontend.
- Is context key here, e.g. calling font apis from the
  frontend is probably best, but fetching and needing to process data
  is probably better from the backend.

What do others recommend (and do) and are there any other for or against points to add to the 'thoughts' too?

Comment: I would say it depend what kind of thirdpartyservice and what you use them for :) All frontend dependencies should be call from frontend and all backend dependencies from backend.

Comment: If you don't want to process the response from the API, then front-end will do. But if you call the API from the backend, you get additional flexibility of manipulating the response (useful when you get a huge data in response), filtering, adding additional data and more with the compromise on extra load on the server. It depends on what you want to do with the response :)

Comment: All very helpful, yes additional processing of the data, and maybe adding data to a database at the same time would definitely be a job for the backend. I think seeing it in terms of frontend dependencies called from the frontend and backend dependencies from the backend is a good way of looking at it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what your 3rd party API requires.

If you need some credentials to call the API it's probably better to handle the call in backend because of security concerns.

If the API delivers time sensitive data, like some auto-complete information as you type, it might be good to not do the extra roundtrip to the backend and call it from the frontend.

You might create a subdomain which points to the 3rd party server,
like 3rdparty-api.yourdomain.com, this removes a lot of cross-domain issues.  But this needs cooperation of your 3rd party provider.

So, there is no clear yes or no answer but it depends on the situation and focus of your API.

Comment: Interesting, I'd never thought about creating a subdomain to try and remove the cross-domain issues, will look into that

Comment: The subdomain is an interesting idea, but I think a lot of APIs would be more likely to already support CORS than custom CNAMEs. Having said that, if their APIs respond to an IP address without needing the hostname.... then there'd be nothing stopping you ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would say we should also take care about code duplication. In your case you are all JavaScript, but that is not true for many others. So let's say I consume `api.github.com` so I will not want to make some calls from frontend and some from the backend, then I think creating a controller which will handle all of this is a good choice.

Except for the cases like any analytics or tracking software, an extra round trip is ok.

As @Wolffc said, this can also prevent sending `access_token` to the browser which may be misused.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution looks fine, the only thing that may get in your way is if the 3rd party API you are using provides any sort of analytics. If you call it from Node you will overwrite the Agent and IP information that would be gathered if you called from UI. Other than that, I believe making the request directly from UI could reduce a little bit the load on the server, but I don't know if that matters to you.